# Is fulltext search can search for part of a string with MySql + Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7

I need to know how full-text search can be used in Laravel to find records with part of a string in the MySQL table

search string: "mori"

The search result should return a record with: "Memorial Fountain"

Expected outcome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0gRD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's `FULLTEXT` can handle *initial* strings, but not final or internal strings.  That is, this should work:

```
MATCH(foo) AGAINST('memo*')
```

This will search for `mori`, but it will be slow since it need to check each row:

WHERE foo LIKE '%mori%'